# Jenkins plugin, how to execute system command on remote node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our company's Jenkins has master and two slave nodes. I am writing plugin for it. One of the things for plugin to do is to checkout some files from svn. This action cannot be extracted from plugin.
To do this I execute console command "svn checkout" from java code of my plugin. The problem is that files from svn are checked out to master, rather than to slave nodes.
How can I make files be checked out to slave?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have these objects, usually received as parameters for `perform` method:

```
Launcher launcher;
AbstractBuild<?, ?> build;
BuildListener listener;
```

Then you have created and added arguments to an argumentListBuilder, maybe something like:

```
ArgumentListBuilder command = new ArgumentListBuilder();
command.addTokenized("xcopy /?");
```

Then, do something like:

```
ProcStarter ps = launcher.new ProcStarter();
ps = ps.cmds(command).stdout(listener);
ps = ps.pwd(build.getWorkspace()).envs(build.getEnvironment(listener));
Proc proc = launcher.launch(ps);
int retcode = proc.join();
```

ProcStarter will run the command at the node specified by the `launcher` instance. But please at least glance over the javadocs of all above classes before using, above is *not* direct copy-paste from working code.

Comment: There is one issue with it: "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified." I tried either command "svn co"  and "cmd.exe /C svn co".  Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: @V.Artyukhov How did you construct `command`? Just a guess, without seeing your code, but you should maybe `ArgumentListBuilder.addTokenized(java.lang.String s)`

Comment: Hi, I tried to do the same thing with but with a maven command, and I have errors with jenkins. When I go to the console output to see the result of my build, when I go back to another, I got error with jenkins UI (css, javascript, etc). Maybe it has something with the maven command output. Here is what I get when I launch with the mvn command http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/jenkins.png/. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: @Dimitri asking that as a comment to another answer is not very useful, comments are not chat, try posting your own question.

Comment: OK sorry, I took the advantage to ask you the question. I will post my question lately.

Comment: @Dimitri in any case, the code in this answer should have nothing what so ever to do with messed up Jenkins HTML output, problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I am getting following error using the above example:

`[Project Builder Test] $ .\tools\bin\bootstrap.exe tools load -a --project my_project
ERROR - IOException occurred: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ".\tools\bin\bootstrap.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Project Builder Test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

When I copy the exact same command to the console and run it within the workspace folder under Project Builder Test, it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code based on Hyde's answer, suitable for the Groovy script console (at `/script`)

```
def static Run(nodeName, runCommand)
{
    def output = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    def listener = new hudson.util.StreamTaskListener(output);
    def node = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getNode(nodeName);
    def launcher = node.createLauncher(listener);

    def command = new hudson.util.ArgumentListBuilder();
    command.addTokenized(runCommand);
    def ps = launcher.launch();
    ps = ps.cmds(command).stdout(listener);
    // ps = ps.pwd(build.getWorkspace()).envs(build.getEnvironment(listener));
    def proc = launcher.launch(ps);
    int retcode = proc.join();
    return [retcode, output.toString()]
}

// for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
(recode, output) = Run("build-slave9", "xcopy /?");
println output;
```

(Caveats: untested for programs that read stdin. Note the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, so don't run programs with very long output. Untested for non-ASCII output.)

Comment: I'm testing this out using the script console, and calling createLauncher() is returning a NullPointerException. My goal is to iterate all slaves, and execute a maintenance script on them. Has anyone seen this work?

Comment: It worked for me in April, and works today on Jenkins 1.580.1. The slave must be online for this to work. (And do you have a slave named "build-slave9", or did you change it?)