# How to find the ip address of a jenkins node from the master

Tags: jenkins

Running from the master node scripting console, or from the a system groovy script (that also runs on the master), how do I get the ip address(es) of a slave node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was hoping that this simple script would suffice:

```
import java.net.*

for (slave in Jenkins.instance.slaves) {
  host = slave.computer.hostName
  addr = InetAddress.getAllByName(host)
  println slave.name + ": " + addr.hostAddress
}
```

But at least with my installation, it does not give me the result I want on the systems that have multiple network interfaces.

You could use the "run a command on the slave" technique from [the answer to "How to execute system command on remote node"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23226035/172599) to run something like `/sbin/ifconfig` on each slave. That would certainly give you the details, but I don't have the Groovy savvy to write up an output parser to extract the IPs.

Answer (score 4):

@Dave Bacher's answer will give you all IP's for the given host.
Assuming your slaves are SSH based, this will give you strictly the IP that the agent uses:

```
def jenkins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
for (node in jenkins.nodes) {
  println "${node.nodeName}: ${node.toComputer().launcher.host}"
}
```

Comment: Instead of the approach mentioned above (always returns null) this one finally works to retrieve the host name. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work JNLP connected machines :(