# How to find the IP/Host name of the slave added as a node to the Jenkins Master?

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to find the IP/hostname of the slave node?
Situation here is,

1. no access to the Jenkins master machine.
2. no details to the Slave Machine available.
3. Just we have is to login Jenkins Master dashboard and can see the slaves.

I couldn't able to fins any details of the slaves IP or Hostname.

Your steps to find or suggestions will be appreciated.

This is not same as the below case
[How to find the ip address of a jenkins node from the master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092236/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-a-jenkins-node-from-the-master)

I cannot able to login to the Jenkins master machine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the easiest way to find the node/slave machines IP from Jenkins Master UI.

- Goto Jenkins Master Dashboard page
- Click Manage Jenkins
- Click Manage Nodes
- Click Any Slave Machine
- Click Log

You can see the first line with the IP Address of it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the slave machine Host name is as below,

Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> (Select the Slave Machine ) -> System Properties

Then Look for "Computer Name"